# Assert image uploaded correctly - Selenium

Tags: django, selenium, tdd

I'm using Selenium to test my website. I am making a functional test where it logs a new user in, goes to their profile, then asserts that it can successfully update their profile info. This includes name, email address and profile picture. I can check that the name and email are successfully updated, but don't know how to check that the image uploads correctly.

I am able to upload the image successfully (I used time.sleep(10) to check - I just need an assertion for it.

This is how im uploading the new image

```
self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.clearablefileinput.form-control-file').send_keys(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'\profile_pics\\testImg.jpg')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where does your image get uploaded- a database?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 just to my root MEDIA folder atm. In a years time when I'm finally ready to think about putting it on a server I'll read up on where I should be saving user uploaded images. I'm new to web dev

Comment: So would it not suffice to check that the file name exists in the root media folder? You can check with something like `os.path.isfile(fname) `which returns `true` if it exists or not.

Comment: Great, that would work. I'm guessing then I'd need to delete the image after each run? I'm sure that I'll be able to find a way to do that in Selenium. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can check that the file name exists in the root media folder? You can check with something like

```
os.path.isfile(fname)
#Or
os.path.exists(file_path)
```

which both returns true if it exists or not.

I don't think deleting a file is possible in selenium, since its just an Automator. For that, you would have to use the `os` module again with `remove()` method.

Comment: Also if you have a conflict of image names, you may consider appending the time values to each image that's uploaded and later using that value to safely delete the correct image.